# what is scyther code for this protocol?

Tags: cryptanalysis, attack, protocol-analysis

I wrote the following protocol.
I wrote the code.
I do not know how to write the rest of the code.
please guide me.

usertype SessionKey;

usertype TimeStamp;

hashfunction H1;

macro sessionkey = H();

protocol SCiSH(A,HG)
{

```
role A
{
    fresh VA,RA,NID,VHG,RHG: Nonce;
    fresh T1,T2 :TimeStamp;
    var IDA,IDHG,SK;

    send_1(A,HG, {A,NID,VA,RA,T1}H1(RA) );
    recv_2(HG,A, {VHG,RHG,T2,HG}H1(RHG) );

    claim_A1(A,Secret,NID);
    claim_A2(A,Secret,VA);
    claim_A3(A,Secret,RA);
    claim_A4(A,Secret,VHG);
    claim_A5(A,Secret,RHG);


    claim(A,Secret,sessionkey);
    claim(A,Alive);
    claim(A,Weakagree);
    claim(A,Commit,A,R,S);
    claim(A,Niagree);




}

role HG
    {
    fresh VA,RA,NID,VHG,RHG: Nonce;
    fresh T1,T2 :TimeStamp;
    var IDA,IDHG,SK;

    recv_1(A,HG, {A,NID,VA,RA,T1}H1(RA) );
    send_2(HG,A, {VHG,RHG,T2,HG}H1(RHG) );


    claim_HG1(HG,Secret,NID);   
    claim_HG2(HG,Secret,VA);
    claim_HG3(HG,Secret,RA);
    claim_HG4(HG,Secret,VHG);
    claim_HG5(HG,Secret,RHG);

    claim(HG,Secret,sessionkey);
    claim(HG,Alive);
    claim(HG,Weakagree);
    claim(HG,Commit,A,R,S);
    claim(HG,Niagree);




}
```

}